# I have an error after using php artisan migrate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, websocket

Here is the message I got after the migration.

> **Illuminate\Database\QueryException**
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the
> target machine actively refused it.  (SQL: select * from
> information_schema.tables where table_schema = econnect and table_name
> = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

The errors are both in line 70, which is

```
/**
 * Create a new PDO connection instance.
 *
 * @param  string  $dsn
 * @param  string  $username
 * @param  string  $password
 * @param  array  $options
 * @return \PDO
 */
protected function createPdoConnection($dsn, $username, $password, $options)
{
    if (class_exists(PDOConnection::class) && ! $this->isPersistentConnection($options)) {
        return new PDOConnection($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    }

    return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
}
```

Line 70 is the `return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);`

The first error was `PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.")`

and the second error was `PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=econnect", "root", "", [])`

**UPDATE**

> I made a mistake to not start the MYSQL and APACHE on XAMP, after I
> started it, it worked but there is another error occured which is
>
> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
> 'personal_access_tokens' already exists (SQL: create table
> personal_access_tokens (id bigint unsigned not null auto_increment
> primary key, tokenable_type varchar(255) not null, tokenable_id bigint
> unsigned not null, name varchar(255) not null, token varchar(64) not
> null, abilities text null, last_used_at timestamp null, created_at
> timestamp null, updated_at timestamp null) default character set
> utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

I have 5 migrations files, but here is where the "personal_access_tokens" table

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePersonalAccessTokensTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->morphs('tokenable');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('token', 64)->unique();
            $table->text('abilities')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('last_used_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('personal_access_tokens');
    }
}
```

Comment: As the error said your machine can't make connection with mysql or apache service. Which OS are you using? Are you using `xampp` to start required services?

Comment: I made a mistake to not start the MYSQL and APACHE on XAMP, after I started it, it worked but there is another error occured

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'personal_access_tokens' already exists....

Is that error okay? Nothing to worry about?

Comment: run `php artisan migrate:refresh`. But keep in mind it will delete all the tables and datas from given db and reinstall tables without datas

Comment: The same error still exists.                                              SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'personal_access_tokens' already exists (SQL: create table `personal_access_tokens` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `tokenable_type` varchar(255) not null, `tokenable_id` bigint unsigned not null, `name` 
varchar(255) not null, `token` varchar(64) not null, `abilities` text null, `last_used_at` timestamp null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Comment: Please add your `database/migrations` folder to questions. You may have 2 or more migration file that have different names but the same table name inside

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the services is active (Mysql, apache/nginx) etc.

Comment: Yeah, mybad, I made a mistake to not start the MYSQL and APACHE on XAMP, after I started it, it worked but there is another error occured.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to connect to this database via any mysql client?
It may be a configuration issue on mysql server, typo, or you shouldn't use root user.

If you're using laradock, try to change in .env file
from:

```
DB_CONNECTION=127.0.0.1
```

to:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
```

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake to not start the MYSQL and APACHE on XAMP, after I started it, it worked but there is another error occured